# How to make thumbnails using Imagick::resizeImage appear sharper - PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, resize-image

I am using Imagick::resizeImage to create a thumbnail PNG image of each page of a pdf file.  However, the image I am getting back is really blurry.  How can I make it a little sharper?  Any pointers would be really appreciated.

I have tried adjusting the 'blur' paramter of Imagick::resizeImage between 0.1 - 1, without success.

```
$pdfPage = '1Mpublic.pdf[0]';
$im = new imagick($pdfPage);
$im->setImageFormat('png');

// Resize thumbnail image
$imgHeight =  $im -> getImageHeight();
$imgWidth = $im -> getImageWidth();
$desiredWidth = 200;
$desiredHeight = resizedImageHeight($imgWidth, $imgHeight, $desiredWidth);

$im -> setResolution(1500, 1500);
$im -> resizeImage($desiredWidth, $desiredHeight, imagick::STYLE_NORMAL, 0.1);

 /* Resize image */
function resizedImageHeight($imgWidth, $imgHeight, $desiredImgWidth){

    $quoient = $imgWidth/$imgHeight;
    $height = $desiredImgWidth/$quoient;

    return $height;
}
```

[image]

original pdf link:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4905263/pdf/ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf

Comment: This comment in the PHP docs uses the option to "setResolution": http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.construct.php#113801 - have you tried that?

Comment: @Philip I have tried - please see edit.

Comment: PDF files are vector files that have no pixels and are measure in inches or centimeters. You have to rasterize them to pixels. But to tell it how big to make the raster image, you must tell it the desired resolution you want for the rasterization. So must put the setResolution with a large value such as 300 `before` reading the PDF. But your desired width=200 is too small to get anything resonable

Comment: @fmw42 i am a novice at using imgick. Please could you give me some broad pointers on how to rasterize the pdf and how would i go about setting the resolution before reading the pdf file? my desired width is flexible. perhaps you could share some code?

Comment: You're also using `STYLE_NORMAL` as a parameter for the resize algorithm - that parameter should be one of the `FILTER_` constants (`Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS` for example). But the resolution is the main issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than rendering and then resizing the raster, it might be better to render the PDF to the right number of pixels in the first place. It'll be faster, and you can be sure that the amount of sharpness is correct for the content.

For example:

```
$ time convert -density 50 ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf[0] x2.png
real    0m0.325s
user    0m0.299s
sys 0m0.024s
```

Makes:

[image: direct sizing output]

The `-density 50` makes a page about the same number of pixels across as your sample, 425.

In imagick you could do it like this (as @fmw42's excellent answer already says):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$target_width = 400;

# get natural size, calculate density we need for target width
$im = new imagick();
$im->pingImage($argv[1]);
$geo = $im->getImageGeometry();
$natural_width = $geo['width'];
$density = 72.0 * $target_width / $natural_width;

# load at correct resolution for target_width
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution($density, $density);
$im->readImage($argv[1]);

# and write back
$im->writeImage($argv[2]);
```

Doing both the ping and the read is a little slow in imagick, unfortunately:

```
$ time ./pdfthumb.php ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf x.png
real    0m2.773s
user    0m2.737s
sys 0m0.036s
```

It's not imagick, but [`vipsthumbnail`](http://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html) can do the ping and read in one operation:

```
$ time vipsthumbnail ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf -s 400x -o x2.png
real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.064s
sys 0m0.011s
```

It might be worth considering if speed is important. [libvips has a php binding](https://github.com/jcupitt/php-vips) so you can call it directly, but if you do that you'll run into awful licensing problems because it uses the GPL library poppler for PDF rendering, sigh. ImageMagick uses GhostScript and shells out to that for the same reason.

Comment: thanks for the input, the ask was how would you do this using php - imagick?

Comment: user894763 approach is indeed better than mine. The one issue is that you need to compute the required density to produce the desired pixel size. So you need to run the command once with nominal density of 72 and find the size, then scale the density to achieve the desired output size in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I do not know Imagick that well. But in Imagemagick command line, I would do what is sometimes called supersampling. That is use a large density to read the PDF, then resize down by the inverse scale factor.

For example, nominal density is 72 dpi. I would read the input PDF at 4*72=288 dpi. Then after rasterizing, I would resize by 1/4=25% or for a larger result by something larger than 25%, say 50%. Here is your first page done both ways:

```
convert -density 288 ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf[0] -resize 25% result1.png
```

[image]

```
convert -density 288 ksgt-06-04-1091539.pdf[0] -resize 50% result2.png
```

[image]

In Imagick, the key is something like:

```
$imagick = new Imagick(); 
$imagick->setImageResolution(288, 288);
$imagick->readImage('myfile.pdf');
```