# Imagemagik-convert pdf to pdf without doing anything

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to take a PDF of scanned hand written images, darken it and increase contrast. However, regardless of the command i type into the terminal, the output file looks blurry and the file size is much smaller than the original. It was reduced from 8MB to 1.3 MB

**So how can I convert a pdf to pdf without losing quality?** I tried:

```
convert input.pdf output.pdf
```

but clearly just returns a pdf of blurry images.

Comment: Have you checked the forum for similar questions? There was one earlier this week and another on the same subject last week; hint -density. Imagemagick is a raster image program so your input will be read in, changed to a raster document modified and the saved as a pdf document.

Comment: I typed in all the proposed commands I could find, but didnt work. It seems density just changes the dpi of the output image, for example:  `convert input.pdf -density 72 output.pdf` creates the same blurry image at 72 DPI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the posts you will notice you have to upsize and put density first e.g

```
convert -density 288 input.pdf -resize 25% output.pdf
```

[Last weeks similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828544/how-to-make-thumbnails-using-imagickresizeimage-appear-sharper-php/49850914#49850914)

Comment: I had to resize 100%, but upvoted as this got me there.